# How to change text color in Disqus comment textarea?

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, textarea, disqus

I'm using Disqus external comment system with Wordpress (as a WP plugin) and I'm trying to customize it with my custom CSS.

Everything works great, but I have problems with replacing the default text color in the form textarea.

I tried it with:

```
#dsq-content .dsq-textarea .dsq-textarea-wrapper, #dsq-content .dsq-input-wrapper { color: red !important }
```

but I was not successful, even when I targetet just "textarea" it not worked.

It seems that javascript is playing together because there are 2 events: when the textarea is focused and blurred. When there is a "blur" then .placeholder-grey CSS class is added to the textarea, but targeting that with CSS not worked as well.

Disqus has very poor documentation, so I figured out all this with code inspection.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

P.S. I don't have a working example online, you can see it on any blog/website where Disqus is used, for example on their own blog at: http://blog.disqus.com/post/974280725/achievement-unlocked-merging-profiles#disqus_thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you link to has a css style block just before the textarea, if you edit this to add `color: #f90;` it'll change the color from the usual black to orange (in this example). Presumably you could also add this in the `head` of the document instead.

If you use something like Chrome's developer tools or, I imagine, Firebug for Firefox you can edit the html/css in place to see the effect live (although it won't persist) to see what changes you can, or need to, make.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't solve it yet I found a solution that worked for me. Just a bit after the body{} tag in the style sheet of wordpress, you will find the ul{} in there change the `color:#FFFFFF` to `color:#000000` (or what ever color you like). It worked for me and I hope it will work for you to.

```css
body{
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #000000;
}

a:hover{
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

a {
 color: #CCCCCC;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
}      

li {
 padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}      

ul {
 list-style:none;
 >>> color: #000000;     
 margin-left: 25px;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the theme is laid out, Disqus may inherit a different text color which may be the same as the background. You can change it using the following override:

```
#dsq-content { color: #ffffff !important; }
```

If the text color still does not change, you will need to target comments more directly. This can be done with the following CSS:

```
.dsq-full-comment { color: #ffffff !important; } /*for Narcissus theme users*/

.dsq-comment-body { color: #ffffff !important; } /*for Houdini theme users*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The website you weblink to has a css design prevent just before the textarea, if you modify this to add color: #f90; it'll modify along with from the regular dark to lemon (in this example). Presumably you could also add this in the go of the papers instead.

[Spybubble Free](http://spybubblefreev.com/)