# Change Text Color in Disqus Comment Box

Tags: css, textarea, disqus

This is driving me completely insane. I have Disqus installed on my site and am using custom CSS through the @import method on the Disqus control panel. No matter what I do I CAN. NOT. get the text color in the comment textarea to change.

Here's the part that's really making me crazy: if I modify the `div#comment` selector in Chrome's element inspector, it works. But if I add the style to my stylesheet, **the code doesn't even show up** in the inspector! I'm absolutely certain that I uploaded the CSS file to the server. It's like Disqus is just ignoring my stylesheet for that particular section.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653159/how-to-change-text-color-in-disqus-comment-textarea) is of no use to me because I'm not running Wordpress. And [this article](http://docs.disqus.com/help/69/) by Disqus doesn't even address the issue.

I really like Disqus, but this is just ridiculous. Has anyone else had this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link or something that we can see?

Comment: could you provide the style code?

Comment: If you're uploading the file and it's not changing, your browser doesn't realize the file has changed and needs to be recached. Try clearing your cache for the page and reloading again. Also, try using the `!important` modifier for the `#comment` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the comments are being styled by Disqus with their `embed.js` file that is used to load the comments into your page. Since the JavaScript is processed after your CSS, it is overwriting any styles you put in your stylesheet.

You could try to change the styles with JavaScript (just be sure to include your JavaScript after the Disqus script).

Comment: Yup, that seems to be the case. I can live with keeping that one area the default style rather than bloating the site with javascript. Hopefully Disqus will make customization of that section easier in the future.

Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I came across this after I found a better resolution. To change the Discus comments to white add this to your stylesheet:

```
#disqus_thread {
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Should do the trick. Worked on my end.